# React Native - Activity Recognition Permission Request in XML, still request permissions

Tags: android, react-native, android-manifest, google-fit, google-fit-api

Im using Google fit to track user steps with react-native-google-fit.
After getting user permission to track Activity and Body im getting an error that I need to request permission from user of Activity Recognition.

This is the xml I added (also tried to add LOCATION):

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION"/>
 <!-- <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.gms.permission.LOCATION"/> --> <---- tried with this as well
```

This is the sdk versions in the gradle.build:

```
  buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
  minSdkVersion = 21
  compileSdkVersion = 28
  targetSdkVersion = 29
```

Also added (in gradle.build):

```
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-fitness:20.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:18.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.2.0'
```

This is where the code (Google Fit) execute (HomePage.js - just after user logs in):

```
useEffect(() => {
        const options = {
            scopes: [
                Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_READ,
                Scopes.FITNESS_ACTIVITY_WRITE,
                Scopes.FITNESS_BODY_READ,
                Scopes.FITNESS_BODY_WRITE,
                Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_READ, <---- also tried without
                Scopes.FITNESS_LOCATION_WRITE, <---- also tried without
            ],
        };

        GoogleFit.authorize(options)
            .then(authResult => {
                if (authResult.success) {
                    alert('AUTH_SUCCESS'); <------ alert success
                        GoogleFit.startRecording((callback) => { <----- application crash (see attached image)
                        });
            
                } else {
                    alert('AUTH_DENIED', authResult.message);
                }
            })
            .catch(() => {
                alert('AUTH_ERROR');
            });
    }, []);
```

It doesnt crash on the simulator, only on physical device.
The physical device im using is android with android 10. Tho I need to accommodate version >= 8.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So who ever interested.
We manage to solve it by using a library:
react-native-permissions
so:

```
import { check, PERMISSIONS, request, RESULTS } from 'react-native-permissions';


check(PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION).then(result => {
    switch (result) {
        case RESULTS.UNAVAILABLE:
            console.log('This feature is not available (on this device / in this context)');
            break;
        case RESULTS.DENIED:
            console.log('The permission has not been requested / is denied');
            request(PERMISSIONS.ANDROID.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION).then(() => {
                GoogleFit.startRecording(callback => {
                    console.log(callback);
                });
            });

    ... rest of code....
```